# Why am I unable to add a column name to a data frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

***My Target***

I'd like to add/replace a column name while also removing `Name, dtype` at the end of the data frame

***Data Frame***

```
>>> df

0  Cheese
1  Bread
2  Ham
3  Egg
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

***My Attempt***

I have tried to do the following:

```
df.columns = ['Cart']
```

But when outputting `df`, it appears exactly the same as before hand.

***Expected Output***

```
   Cart
0  Cheese
1  Bread
2  Ham
3  Egg
```

Comment: Your object is a Series, not a DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df` is `Series`, not `DataFrame`.

Use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df.to_frame('Cart')
```

Or:

```
df.rename('Cart').to_frame()
```

---

```
df = pd.Series(['Cheese','Bread','Ham','Egg'], name='Column1')
print (df)
0    Cheese
1     Bread
2       Ham
3       Egg
Name: Column1, dtype: object

print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (df.to_frame('Cart'))
     Cart
0  Cheese
1   Bread
2     Ham
3     Egg
```

Comment: Great answer as always! ;-) Thank You.

Comment: Any downside to `df = pd.DataFrame({'cart': df})` versus `.to_frame` method?

Comment: @Imo - Yes, it is another solution. I try timings and a little bit `to_frame` is faster: `df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)` - `In [139]: %timeit (df.to_frame('Cart'))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.38 ms per loop

In [140]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(dict(Cart=df)))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.52 ms per loop`

Comment: @BenF97 - Thank you. And Happy New Year ;)

Comment: To you too! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

@jezrael's answer is your answer. I just like to add alternatives

Construct from scratch given your `df` is a `pd.Series`

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(Cart=df))
```